# Are there any pure client-side AJAX/javascript Spellchecker plugins?

Tags: ajax, jsonp, spell-checking

Spellify works like a charm, but it entails 2 hops - once to your own server, which then creates a web request and calls out the google API. Expensive - considering it occurs every time any user types a space in one of one's forms.

I am yet to find a pure client-side version that manges to create the 3rd-party request client side (presumably because it is a post and you have x-origin issues) - are there any JSONP / GET solutions out there?

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting I've since stumbled upon the new [HTML5 spellcheck attribute](http://wufoo.com/html5/attributes/17-spellcheck.html).

Our call is that for us the spellcheck is a nice to have - since the latest browsers are all supporting this attribute, overtime more and more of our users will get this feature.

I'd still like to hear about a JSONP solution, as suggested replacements a la spellify would be even better.